# how to move the rows of grid view with out using Scrollbars in .Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

when ever we add one row into the grid view control then already existing row will be move d down and new row will be added up .just like in twitter website.the rows will be automatically moved.

Comment: So, if the new rows are added at the top, isn't scrolling automatically handled by the browsers?
Can you extend your question?

Comment: Your tags are C#, JavaScript and jQuery...which are you using?  Perhaps some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rani did you try catching the row by id and call the focus() function it will do the focus to the element added for you ??

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter&bih=855&biw=1280&hl=en&tbm=mbl&cad=h                       In the above web site messages will be moved downwords,in this way in my application with in the grid view control the rows will be moved down automatically when ever new row will be added.so how to apply the styles for the grid view control.